# How can I search a phrase mention in string text in Python?

Tags: python, search, text, python-re, findall

Please, can you help me with the following doubt?

I have a text:

```
text = VLOG - Primer evento de la temporada #ModaenTiktok #eventotiktok #madrid @Tik Tok españa
```

And I need to extract only the mention:

`@Tik Tok españa`

What is the most affordable approach to do it?

I tried with:

```
regex = re.compile("(^|\W)(?:@)([A-Za-z0-9_](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]|(?:\.(?!\.))){0,28}(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]))?)", re.UNICODE)

mention = regex.findall(text)
```

But I got only `Tik`.

Comment: What do you want exactly? If you just need to check if `@Tik Tok españa` is in the text, just use `in` operator.

Comment: What if the text was `'@Tik Tok españa qué pasa'` How would I know that the handle is `@Tik Tok españa` and not `@Tik Tok` or `@Tik Tok españa qué`? Do you already know the exact handle you need to extract?

Comment: Hey @Aurelien! I need to extract it since I'll implement it in a loop to analyse several texts at once. The result should be a list including all mentions from this loop.

ALso, to begin with, I am not aware that a mention can exist; only I'm sure about @.

Comment: Do you need to get all texts that include `@Tik Tok españa`? Or just remove `@Tik Tok españa` from the text? Or something else?

Comment: I need to get all texts that include `@` but on some occasions, the text can have spaces (e.g.: `@Tik Tok españa`), so this is my problem.

Comment: @It_is_Chris In such case, a `len` limitation of words would be implemented. In my case, it's very strange that a mention can have more than 4, 5 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to your question, it seems you are trying to collect `@` tags, that may or may not have spaces. From the text, we can see that these tags start with `@`, but never allow `#` as this is a hashtag and not a tag. Therefore we can use these two rules to write a very simple regex solution as :

`re.compile(r"\@[^\#\@\n]+?(?= *[\#\@\n]|$)")`

More verbose, here we are collecting any text starting with `@`, and collecting anything (excluding other @'s, #'s, or hard returns (just good practice)), and ceasing when the next character is either another `@` tag, a `#`, or the end of the string\line. I added a  `*` to the beginning of the lookahead as this will allow the regex to ignore any trailing spaces as well, but this is optional.

You can see it work here: https://regex101.com/r/2T07b0/1